# Error in Convert function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I wrote the following SQL on MSACCESS

```
SELECT 
    Followup.MRN, Followup.dateentered, Followup.formname, 
    (Followup.MRN & Format([Followup.dateentered], "yyyymmdd") 
     & Followup.formname) 
     AS UniqueMilestoneID
FROM Followup;
```

it worked fine

Now when I write this in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
   Followup.MRN, Followup.dateentered, Followup.formname, 
   (Followup.MRN & Convert([Followup.dateentered], "yyyymmdd") 
    & Followup.formname) AS UniqueMilestoneID
FROM Followup
```

I get the following error

> *Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Invalid column name 'yyyymmdd'.
>
>   Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Type Followup.dateentered is not a defined system type.*

Any idea how to overcome the error of the "convert" function

Comment: You put field/object names in double quotes , strings in single quotes in SQLServer. "val" interpreted as column name, 'val' as string value.

Comment: You need to use SQL Server **2012** which has a [new `FORMAT` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) to do this kind of date formatting. For other versions of SQL Server, check out the proper [syntax for `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and how to get the format you need

Comment: When you are doing this sort of thing, remember msaccess is wildly non-standard in terms of sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT 
   Followup.MRN, Followup.dateentered, Followup.formname, 
   Followup.MRN + 
      Convert(char(8), Followup.dateentered, 112) + 
      Followup.formname AS UniqueMilestoneID
FROM Followup
```

Here is a reference of [date formats in SQL Server](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/).  Also to concatenate strings in SQL server you want to use the `+` sign instead of the `&`

Answer (score 2):

First, string constants in SQL Server are delimited by single quotes, not double quotes.

Second, convert does not take arguments in that form.  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

What I think you want is:

```
convert(varchar(8), Followup.DateEntered, 112)
```